# 404 errors with Nginx

Tags: caching

I'm trying to test nginx on Dreamhost following the instructions in the wiki, but going to any page except for the front page results in a 404 error: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Nginx#Drupal.

Certain things are assumed, and from that assumption I cannot tell if they apply to what I'm trying to do or not. I'm guessing its some kind of clean URL based error.

For example, /home/YOURUSER/nginx/example.com/drupal.conf; my path is /home/YOURUSER/example.com/drupal.conf.

I'm assuming at this point that is not the issue.  I've tried various things including just putting in what appears to be the bare minimum to no effect:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

Any pointers would be helpful.  I'd like to get this working with Boost.

I also attempted to use this: http://wiki.nginx.org/Drupal#Not_So_Simple.

Disabling clean URLs allows me to log in, and Drupal states that clean URLs are not enabled.

Comment: DreamHost changed its site knowledge base to this new URL: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216431827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it seemed odd, I created a nginx/site.com and put the .conf there.  I am accustomed to .htaccess, but apparently this file does not belong even in the same dir so in the end it was just a silly mistake with where I put the .conf.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use (with Drupal 6 and Boost), most is self explanatory but I added additional comments here and there:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     IP.NR example.com www.example.com;  # Multiple hostnames seperated by spaces
        root            /path/to/drupal; # Replace this
        charset         utf-8;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log  combined;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

        index  index.php;

        if ($host ~* (^example.com|www.example2.com)) { # Redirect to www.example.com
                rewrite ^(.*)   http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
        }

    ## 6.x starts
        location / {
                #rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; # remove trailing slashes - disabled
                try_files $uri @cache;
        }

        location @cache {
                if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
                        return 405;
                }
                if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
                        return 405;
                }
                error_page  405 = @drupal;
                add_header  Expires "Tue, 24 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT";
                add_header  Cache-Control "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
                add_header  X-Header "Boost Citrus 1.9";
                charset         utf-8;
                try_files   /cache/normal/$host${uri}_$args.html /cache/$host${uri}_$args.html @drupal;
        }

        location @drupal {
                ###
                ### now simplified to reduce rewrites
                ###
                rewrite ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1 last;
        }

        location ~*
        (/\..*|settings\.php$|\.(htaccess|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|pl|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template))$
        {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~* /files/.*\.php$ {
                return 444;
        }
        location ~* /themes/.*\.php$ {
                return 444;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri @drupal;           #check for existence of php file
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
                include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php_fpm; # Includes config for PHP-FPM (see below)
        }

        location ~ \.css$ {
                if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
                        return 405;
                }
                if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
                        return 405;
            }
                error_page 405 = @uncached;
                #access_log     off;
                expires         max; #if using aggregator
                add_header      X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.1";
            try_files   /cache/perm/$host${uri}_.css /cache/$host${uri}_.css $uri =404;
        }

        location ~ \.js$ {

                if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
                        return 405;
                }
                if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
                    return 405;
                }
                error_page 405 = @uncached;
                #access_log  off;
                expires  max; # if using aggregator
                add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.2";
            try_files /cache/perm/$host${uri}_.js /cache/$host${uri}_.js $uri =404;
        }

        location @uncached {
                #access_log  off;
                expires  max; # max if using aggregator, otherwise sane expire time
        }

        location ~* /files/imagecache/ {
                #access_log         off;
                try_files $uri @drupal;  #imagecache support - now it works
        }

        location ~* /files/backup_migrate/ {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
                #access_log  off;
            expires          14d;
            try_files $uri = 404;
        }


        location ~* \.xml$ {
                if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
                        return 405;
                }
                if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
                        return 405;
                }
                error_page 405 = @drupal;
                add_header Expires "Tue, 24 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT";
                add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
                add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.4";
                charset utf-8;
                types { }
                default_type application/rss+xml;
                try_files /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.xml /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.html /cache/$host${uri}_.xml $uri @drupal;
        }

        location ~* /feed$ {
                if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
                        return 405;
                }
                if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
                        return 405;
                }
                error_page 405 = @drupal;
                add_header Expires "Tue, 24 Jan 1984 08:00:00 GMT";
                add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
                add_header X-Header "Boost Citrus 2.5";
                charset utf-8;
                types { }

                default_type application/rss+xml;
                try_files /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.xml /cache/normal/$host${uri}_.html /cache/$host${uri}_.xml $uri @drupal;
        }

#        error_page  404              /index.php;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
#        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
#        location = /50x.html {
#            root   html;
#        }


        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}

        location /server-status {
                stub_status on;
                access_log off;

        }

     }
```

I'm using PHP-FPM (which is included in PHP 5.3 but I'm using 5.2) so I also include this file (...conf.d/php_fpm)

```
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;    #php-fpm listening on port 9000
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING   $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE   $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI   $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

        # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
        fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout            180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout            180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size             128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size   256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    256k;
#   fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
```

Just ask if you have any questions about specificities.